# Joomla SQL Query Debug Method

Tags: mysql, sql, debugging, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm planning to debug Joomla site by entering each query and it's query execution time to a database table. I have more than 10 models which have different queries. I'm pretty sure that all the queries go through a single place/class before executing but I have no idea where/what the place/class is.

My issue is, Is there a central place I can edit to log the database query and the execution time of a SQL query? I mean like edit a core file just to log every SQL query & it's execution time.

How can I get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to do this programmatically with brute force, it seems it would be far easier and less intrusive to use a proper SQL benchmarking tool such as [MySQL Benchmark Suite](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-benchmarks.html)  Another possible non-brute-force option might be [Toad World](http://www.toadworld.com/MYSQL/SpotlightonMySQL/tabid/620/Default.aspx)

If you wanted to stay away from third-party tools, a [slow query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html) might be the place to start.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using Joomla's built-in [System Debug](http://learn.theartofjoomla.com/developing-extensions/setting-up-your-joomla-site-for-debugging.html)?

Comment: You could very likely create a copy the system debug plugin to log each query in a table. For example, take a look at /plugins/system/debug/debug.php in Joomla 2.5. But, I don't see where Joomla calculates execution time of each query.

Remember that you should never modify core files, and that plugins are a great way to extend core functionality without hacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it via joomla (hack):

1. Goto joomla's database driver, for 3.3 that is:
      **libraries/joomla/database/driver.php**
2. **Remove the setDebug** function
      *(in case some component set it to 0)*
3. At start of file change
       **`$debug = false;` into `$this->debug = true;`**

Now, every query gets logged together with profile information.

Comment: Dear where is file with logged debug statements?